# How can I use styled components for an element that doesn't appear on initial render?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have found that styled components, when not included in the initial render tree, present without the correct CSS.

Here is one example:

I have a paginated 'wizard' interface, which shows back and next buttons.  On the first page, there is no back button for obvious reasons.  However, presumably because the back button doesn't get its conditional CSS rendered initially, styled components does not set up a class for it.  On subsequent pages, the back button appears without any styling at all:

```
<ButtonRow>
  {canGoBack && (
  <Button text='Back' />
  )}
  {canAdvance && (
  <Button primary leftSpaced text='Next' />
  )}
</ButtonRow>
```

`canGoBack = false` on first render, `true` after the user advances.  But after advancing, the back button appears with no CSS at all, just an out-of-the-box HTML button.

I realize I could do something like giving the secondary button 0 opacity rather than leaving it out of the render tree entirely, but there are other contexts where I would like to change the render tree depending on state, and I can't figure out how to get styled components to work in such scenarios.

Here is the `Button` class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 9px 44px 8px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    ${props => props.primary ? css`
        color: #FFF;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #A0A0A0;
        background-color: #3E8FF6;
    ` : css`
        color: #555;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #F0F0F0;
        background-color: #FFF;
    `}
    ${props => props.leftSpaced && css`
        margin-left: 6px;
    `}
    &:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
`;

export default class Button extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <StyledButton
                onClick={this.didClick}
                primary={this.props.primary}
                type={this.props.type || 'button'}
                leftSpaced={this.props.leftSpaced}>{this.props.text}</StyledButton>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the implementation for `SecondaryButton` component?

Comment: I've now included the exact code, I may have oversimplified too much in my first version of this question.  I'm actually still simplifying a bit because I do need state on my Button component, have just removed that for compactness here.

Comment: This same problem happens for me with styled components that are not rendered initially, even in the same file.

Comment: Hmm, I have been unsuccessful at reproducing this issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kjkbqe?file=index.js. Maybe there is something I'm missing. As you can see in my sample, I tried to make the button not render initially.

Comment: You're right!  It works there and on my local machine.  I must have something wonky in my project setup.  Will investigate further in a couple days.  Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Oluwafemi Sule's help, I was able to get to the bottom of this problem.  This was a very, very specific conflict, not a general issue.  In my project, I am using a plugin to cytoscape, `cytoscape-node-html-label` (https://github.com/kaluginserg/cytoscape-node-html-label), which appears to write style tags in conflict with `styled-components`.  As soon as I disable it, my styled components render perfectly as in Oluwafemi's demo in the comments.